# Changing Filename Copy / Paste Between Workbooks - Please review my code that 90% works

Tags: excel, vba

I am a completely new to VBA

The goal of my code below is to **open another excel workbook on a networked drive that's name changes with the month, copy and paste that data into thisworkbook, and close the file I just opened once its done with its task**.

When I F8 through the VBA Editor this code actually works, as it in opens the excel file / copy pastes data, however I'm getting a yellow highlight around the `filepath` string that I made a variable when I try to actually run the macro (and it does not work).

The `filepath` is a concatenation of the `text&cellreference&text` within the Excel workbook, I'm wondering if that is causing the problem. The text is the `filepath`, the cell reference is the changing month.  The month in the filepath is spelled out, aka C:...\location\November 2020 report.xlsx

```
Sub CopyDay1Report()

Dim Day1Report As Variant
Day1Report = Curtailment.Range("Q4")

'GVS1
Excel.Workbooks.Open (Day1Report)
Sheets("GVS1").Range("A1:M16").Copy

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Range("B27:N42").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

'GVS2
Excel.Workbooks.Open (Day1Report)
Sheets("GVS2").Range("A1:M16").Copy

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Range("B47:N62").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

'GVS3
Excel.Workbooks.Open (Day1Report)
Sheets("GVS3").Range("A1:M16").Copy

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Range("B66:N81").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

'GVS4
Excel.Workbooks.Open (Day1Report)
Sheets("GVS4").Range("A1:M16").Copy

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Range("B84:N99").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Workbooks("Day1Report").Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Comment: If `cellreference` is a date then VBA could be reading it as a number - 44186 for today's date as it's that many days since 1st Jan 1900. Try wrapping it within `Format` - `Format(cellreference, "dd-mmm-yy")` for example.

Comment: I think `Day1Report` should be defined as `string`. Also, you use multiple times `Excel.Workbooks.Open (Day1Report)` without closing it. You can't open an already opened workbook, this will raise an error.

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns should I use Activate instead of Worksbooks.Open?

Comment: You should avoid Select / Activate entirely.   [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251)